# не удается запустить скрипт на ubuntu с веб сайта при помощи subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

Окружение: ubuntu16, python 3.8, venv, nginx, flask, gunicorn.Запуск от www-data
В коде на сайте

```
res =  subprocess.call('sudo /var/www/site/script.sh',shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

ошибка syslog : 16:23:46 proxy gunicorn[25450]: /bin/bash: sudo: command not found

Проверял следующим образом. на хосте Ubuntu активировал виртуальную среду,переключался на пользователя www-data, стартовал питон, import subprocess,в консоли питона ввожу:

```
subprocess.call('sudo /var/www/site/script.sh',shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

и все великолепно отрабатывает. Возможно лишняя информация, но в sudoers прописано:

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/www/site/script.sh
```

Т.е. мне нужно передать sudo и скрипт отработает без просьбы ввести пароль от пользователя www-data

Пробовал передавать аргументы так:

['sudo','/var/www/site/script.sh'] (как показано в документации), а так же /bin/bash передать в аргументы, но не работает.

Добился когда скрипт работает с сайта только в случае когда даем права скрипту rwxrwxrwx. хозяин www-data:www-data, тогда все работает, но мне требуется в скрипте переназначать владельцев файлов, а это требует повышения привилегий, т.е. та же команда sudo Передавать пароль скрипту тоже не хотелось бы.

Comment: command not found это очень странно... А покажите где и как вы запускаете gunicorn? В частности systemd-юнит если есть

Comment: @andreymal cat /etc/systemd/system/site.service  .вместо реального имени сайта для краткости пишу site

[Unit]

Description=Gunicorn instance to serve site users

After=network.target


[Service]

User=www-data

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=site

Environment="PATH=/var/www/site/venv/bin"

ExecStart=/var/www/site/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 8 --bind unix:site.sock -m 007 wsgi:app



[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

ps: не разберусь с форматированием в комментариях. Перенос строки не работает (

Comment: В вашем переопределённом PATH нету стандартных системных каталогов (таких как /usr/bin), соответственно система и не может найти команду sudo в указанном вами каталоге /var/www/site/venv/bin

Comment: Но зачем вы переопределили PATH вообще? Вроде бы и без него должно всё работать, venv автоматически отредактирует PATH под свои личные нужды

Comment: @andreymal Вы мой спаситель! Работает! Огромное спасибо! Удалил PATH
Делал по статье(ссылка внизу), подумал, что если не прописать системную переменную к виртуальному окружению. система не сможет взять оттуда пакеты, и будет искать по стандартным путям питона
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru
Там в статье указано: Теперь составим карту рабочего каталога и зададим переменную среды PATH, чтобы система инициализации знала, что исполняемые файлы этого процесса находятся в нашей виртуальной среде.